# Creating a virtual host for laravel project

Tags: php, apache

[image: httpd-vhost]

[image: hosts]

[image: xampp config**strong text**]

I am using `localhost:8080`. Does this make any difference while virtual hosting? when I enter `lsapp.test` in browser, it says page cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your port to `8080` in `httpd-vhosts` file

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

then restart your `apache` server and access like this `lsapp.test:8080`.

Comment: try `lsapp.test:8080`.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for appreciating.

Comment: But apache server is running on port 8080.